# Understanding the effect of additional hidden layers

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

Almost all write ups that speak about this include this piece of text:

> 0 : Only capable of representing linear separable functions or
> decisions.
>
> 1 : Can approximate any function that contains a continuous mapping
> from one finite space to another.
>
> 2 : Can represent an arbitrary decision boundary to arbitrary
> accuracy with rational activation functions and can approximate any
> smooth mapping to any accuracy.

I cannot seem to grasp the difference between the last two statements, too my understanding we can already pproximate any smooth mapping to absolue accuracy using one hidden layer if we use infinite neurons, so the question here is what does that second hidden layer add?